# leaf name and type name can be same in yang

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf, jncryptor, ietf, yang

Below example is correct yang statement or not? it is valid by pyang but JNC is unable to process

```
grouping TLId {
leaf age {
type Age;
mandatory true;
}
}

typedef Age {
type string {
pattern '[0-9][0-9]';
}
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: As mentioned by @predi, this is a valid statement. Most likely this is a JNC bug/limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Your YANG snippet is valid.

Typedefs are assigned to a different namespace compared to schema node identifiers - there can never be a name conflict between a leaf identifier and a typedef identifier, as decribed in [Section 6.2.1 of RFC7950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.2.1):

> Each identifier is valid in a namespace that depends on the type of
> the YANG item being defined.  All identifiers defined in a namespace
> MUST be unique.

> o  All derived type names defined within a parent node or at the top
> level of the module or its submodules share the same type
> identifier namespace.  This namespace is scoped to all descendant
> nodes of the parent node or module.  This means that any
> descendant node may use that typedef, and it MUST NOT define a
> typedef with the same name.

> o  All leafs, leaf-lists, lists, containers, choices, rpcs, actions,
> notifications, anydatas, and anyxmls defined (directly or through
> a "uses" statement) within a parent node or at the top level of
> the module or its submodules share the same identifier namespace.
> This namespace is scoped to the parent node or module, unless the
> parent node is a case node.  In that case, the namespace is scoped
> to the closest ancestor node that is not a case or choice node.